# sapling tree gen в Blender. Преобразование в объект

Tags: 3d, blender

Нашёл в Blender дополнение sapling tree gen для генерации деревьев. Сгенерировал дерево и пытался наложить кору на ствол, но не получается поскольку дерево не сконвертировано в стандартный объект к которому можно прикрепить текстурную карту. И к тому же объект не экспортируется. Как конвертировать дерево в стандартный объект?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая команда:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>С</kbd> -> To Mesh

Comment: Alt+C - Опечатался

Comment: Спасибо заработало

Comment: А почему эту же модель не экспортирует ? все в формате Mesh.?

Comment: Нет, кривая была

Comment: я говорю про то что об`ект уже преобразовано в  Mesh и не экспортирует.

Comment: Так вы же написали, что заработало? Про экспорт создавайте отдельный вопрос. Не забудьте указать какой формат

Comment: Да я смог наложить текстуру  но не экспортировать. вот новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750995/blender-3d-Не-экспортирует-модель