# Blender 3D Не экспортирует модель

Tags: 3d, blender, моделирование

Пытаюсь экспортировать модель но
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал объект дерево с помощью плагина sapling tree gen преобразовал в mesh задавал вопрос как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748330/sapling-tree-gen-%D0%B2-blender-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82) но модель не экспортируется ни в какой формат. Сохраняет blend.

[Скачать модель.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14l82MmvsH5ukFv4vZO1yvbhkmF31KV8Z)

Comment: Кириллица есть в пути? Попробуйте в другое место сохранить

Comment: Плоскость экспортируется а столбур и листья нет.  соответственно с путём все в порядке.

Comment: Сложно сказать, не имея сцены, загрузите файл https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ,чтобы его можно было посмотреть

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14l82MmvsH5ukFv4vZO1yvbhkmF31KV8Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша модель слишком большая для 3DS. Blender выдает сообщение об ошибке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В формате 3DS есть ограничение, максимальное количество точек и полигонов - 65536: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.3ds#Shortcomings

Вместо 3DS попробуйте другой, более современный формат, например, fbx или alembic.

Comment: Спасибо вам, никогда бы не подумал что такое возможно. исходя из вашего ответа о лимите, применил модификатор упрощение, и всё экспортировало. спасибо вам огромное.